# numpy copyto ValueError

Tags: python, numpy

Am I doing an ovious mistake? 
copyto results in;
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (107,77,3) into shape (108,78,3)

```
a = np.ones((107, 77, 3), np.float)
b = np.zeros((108,78, 3), np.float)
np.copyto( b,a)
```

Comment: The arrays must be the same shape, or at least have [broadcast-compatible dimensions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules).

Comment: well basically I am trying to paste and RGB image to another. one image is smaller than the other. How can I paste the members of smaller array into a larger one?

Comment: This just became an altogether different question. [Here is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7115957/3005167)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "embed" a small numpy array into a predefined block of a large numpy array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115437/how-to-embed-a-small-numpy-array-into-a-predefined-block-of-a-large-numpy-arra)