# link two numpy arrays centered

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array

```
blackImg = np.zeros((1920, 1080, 3), np.uint8)
```

I then have another numpy array which is an actual image with a resolution smaller than 1920x1080.

I then want to insert the actual image over the black 1920x1080 image.
The image should be inserted centered.

Like this:
[image: np_link]

Comment: Did you try to write any code yet? How far did you get? I'm not sure you'll find anyone wants to just write this for you...

Comment: The basic idea is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7115437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

```
Img = np.ones((480, 640, 3), np.uint8)
```

is the image, then:

```
NewImg = np.pad(Img, [(720, 720), (220, 220),(0,0)], mode='constant')
```

should add a black padding around the original image. (720, 720) add 720 black pixels at top and bottom (220, 220) adds 220 left and right and (0,0) is to not add padding in the third dimension.

Comment: Maybe explain where the magic numbers come from and link to the docs for `np.pad`.